# How do I create a non staked account on jungle testenet?

Tags: accounts, testnet

I get the following error while trying to create account using the `cleos create wallet` api.

`./cleos.sh create account safarilion12 testacc43211 EOS8jd4VBQ8e5Yy7voS12LB4XL1vH112VNQPFQ7wu6PWF77FwRpLU EOS8jd4VBQ8e5Yy7voS12LB4XL1vH112VNQPFQ7wu6PWF77FwRpLU
Error 3080001: account using more than allotted RAM usage
Error Details:
account testacc43211 has insufficient ram; needs 2996 bytes has 0 bytes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you always have to stake something to have the account:

First check that the creator account (e.g. `accname1`) has funds...

`./cleos.sh get currency balance eosio.token accname1`

... and the output might be something like...

```
832.5970 EOS
```

...and then check what NET and CPU `accname1` has remaining:

`./cleos.sh get account accname1`

e.g.

```
privileged: false
permissions:
     owner     1:    1 EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
        active     1:    1 EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
memory:
     quota:     438.3 Mb     used:     2.926 Kb

net bandwidth: (averaged over 3 days)
     staked:          0.0000 EOS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:     100.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:                 0 bytes
     available:        46.13 Mb
     limit:            46.13 Mb

cpu bandwidth: (averaged over 3 days)
     staked:          0.0000 EOS           (total stake delegated from account to self)
     delegated:     100.0000 EOS           (total staked delegated to account from others)
     used:                 0 us
     available:        1.017 sec
     limit:            1.017 sec
```

So 'available' is 0 and you can delegate resources from another account or itself:

`./cleos.sh system delegatebw eosio accname1 "1.0000 EOS" "1.0000 EOS"`

(first EOS parameter is amount of NET, second is amount of CPU)

To make a new account called `accname2`, specify the resources to go with it:

`./cleos.sh system newaccount accname1 accname2 PUB PUB -p accname1 --stake-net "0.1 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.1 EOS" --buy-ram-EOS "0.1 EOS"`

where `PUB` is the public key of `accname1`

and you should get something like

```
executed transaction: a1dab3d7e920749d35be4f4b610f76e7b5d7bc89aacb8855c7cc09de07d52916  344 bytes  5938 us
#         eosio <= eosio::newaccount            {"creator":"accname1","name":"accname2","owner":{"threshold":1,"keys":[{"key":"EOS7Lpq5SUkGZ...
#         eosio <= eosio::buyram                {"payer":"accname1","receiver":"accname2","quant":"0.1000 EOS"}
#   eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.ram","quantity":"0.0995 EOS","memo":"buy ram"}
#      accname1 <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.ram","quantity":"0.0995 EOS","memo":"buy ram"}
#     eosio.ram <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.ram","quantity":"0.0995 EOS","memo":"buy ram"}
#   eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.ramfee","quantity":"0.0005 EOS","memo":"ram fee"}
#      accname1 <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.ramfee","quantity":"0.0005 EOS","memo":"ram fee"}
#  eosio.ramfee <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.ramfee","quantity":"0.0005 EOS","memo":"ram fee"}
#         eosio <= eosio::delegatebw            {"from":"accname1","receiver":"accname2","stake_net_quantity":"0.1000 EOS","stake_cpu_quanti...
#   eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.stake","quantity":"0.2000 EOS","memo":"stake bandwidth"}
#      accname1 <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.stake","quantity":"0.2000 EOS","memo":"stake bandwidth"}
#   eosio.stake <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"accname1","to":"eosio.stake","quantity":"0.2000 EOS","memo":"stake bandwidth"}
```

the above should work for the latest master of eosio

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Yes this clears my doubt.. Thanks. Although I have a few more questions. How do I decide how much EOS to stake while creating new accounts (I am integrating EOS for an exchange). And can I undelegate the resources once an account completes a transaction.?

Comment: That will become more clear with time - the consensus at present is first to use 0.1 EOS to buy ram, stake 0.45 EOS in CPU, another 0.45 EOS in network. You can unstake but you will need to wait ~3 days for it to come back in (as it is a deferred transaction). You should be able to try out creation on a testnet - if your account is doing a lot of transactions then it will need to stake more

Answer (score 1):

I found this line in the code:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.cpp#L126

```
2. new accounts must stake a minimal number of tokens (as set in system parameters)
therefore, this method will execute an inline buyram from receiver for newacnt in
an amount equal to the current new account creation fee.
```